# Can't see my navigationbar custom button, but it is clickable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want to add a custom button (to the right) in my navigation bar.

I have the following code in my "viewDidLoad" function :

```
UIButton *audioBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[audioBtn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"];
[audioBtn setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[audioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleAudioPlayback:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:audioBtn];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;

[audioBtn release];
[button release];
```

I can't see the button in my navigation bar, but if I click to the right (where the button is supposed to be), it triggers the function "toggleAudioPlayback", so the only problem is that I don't see the button!

I tried with different image, setting a background color, nothing works...

By the way, I use this image somewhere else in the code, and I see it (on a custom button, but not in a navigationBar).

Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your life easier and instead of a customView just use a UIBarButtonItem with a custom image:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *audioBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleAudioPlayback:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = audioBtn;
    [audioBtn release];
```

---

**UPDATE**

Since you have indicated you want your button to not have a border, then you will need to use a CustomView afterall, but I have modified your code to make this work *(the key difference is the assigning of the frame, which is set to the size of the image, but you could set it to a custom size to have the image centered)*:

```
UIButton *audioBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *playImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"];
[audioButton setBackgroundImage:playImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[audioButton setBackgroundImage:playImg forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
audioBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,playImg.size.width,playImg.size.height);
[audioBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleAudioPlayback:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:audioBtn];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
[audioBtn release];
[button release];
```

Comment: It works, but there's a border on the button. I didn't find how to remove that border.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[[UIButton alloc] init]` try the `+buttonWithType:` method on UIButton.